# error in returning result in doInBackGround() in Async task

Tags: android

Here i am placing doinBackground() having problem in return the response.

```
@Override
protected string doInBackground(string... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                        "http://motinfo.direct.gov.uk/internet/jsp/ECHID-Internet-History-Request.jsp");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        3);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "Vehicle registration mark from number plate",
                        "123456789"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                        "AP3398"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                        "000000"));

                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                /*String line = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    System.out
                    .println("***********************************************************");
                    xx.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

                }else {

                }*/

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;

        }
```

Comment: what is the problem? and also use `Log` for logging info instead of system.out.println

Comment: problem in last statement return response;

Comment: if last statement returns response what is the problem then?

Comment: response cannot be resolved to a variable ..

Comment: @prabha: HttpResponse response outside try: and use response= client.execute(post);

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
  String _response;
  try
  {
    ... //rest of the code
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);   

  }catch (IOException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  return _repsonse; 
  // return string coz your return type of doInbackground is string
```

Edit

```
     protected string doInBackground(string... params)
```

Shoudl be

```
     protected String doInBackground(String... params)
```

and your return type is also not String

Comment: Nope return type is not `HttpResponse`

Answer (score 1):

*1.* You have Return type `String` and you are `returning response ( HttpResponse )`

*2.* Declare this `HttpResponse response;` before `Try{...` block

*3.* Change to  `response = client.execute(post);`

and

```
return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
```

*4.* Check `protected string doInBackgroun...` `string` ? should be `String`

*5.* You can't update `U`I part in `doInBackground` This Should be done in `onPostExecute()`

so if you uncomment the following will generate `Exception`

```
xx.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

Comment: `response` is still in try block and return is after `catch` block

Answer (score 0):

You can not write this line in background thread

```
xx.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

because you cant update UI from non ui thread.

so write this line in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: @Prabha try this      `HttpResponse response ;
      try
      {
       response = client.execute(post);  
      }`

Comment: i am getting response ,problem in return response statement only.

Comment: @Prabha problem is response variable is local to the try block.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to return a `HttpResponse` which is created in `try-catch` block. So it won't be accessible outside. And the return type of `doInBackgroung` is String.

So either change it to `HttpResponse` or convert `HttpResponse` to string.

Try below code.

```
@Override
    protected string doInBackground(string... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpResponse response
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                    "http://motinfo.direct.gov.uk/internet/jsp/ECHID-Internet-History-Request.jsp");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    "Vehicle registration mark from number plate",
                    "123456789"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                    "AP3398"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                    "000000"));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = client.execute(post);

            /*String line = "";
            if (response != null) {
                System.out
                        .println("***********************************************************");
                xx.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

            }else {

            }*/

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

1. The return type is String and you are trying to return HttpResponse.
2. The scope of response is limited to try-catch block only as you are declaring it in that block.

**Solution:**

Convert response to string and then return it.

Try

```
@Override
protected string doInBackground(string... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpResponse response = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder sb = null;

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                        "http://motinfo.direct.gov.uk/internet/jsp/ECHID-Internet-History-Request.jsp");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        3);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "Vehicle registration mark from number plate",
                        "123456789"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                        "AP3398"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                        "000000"));

                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                try {
            // executes the request and gets the response.
            response = client.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        // convert response to string
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

        String line = "0";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        return sb.toString();                 

        }
```

And update following in `postExecute(String result)`

// line from your code.

```
xx.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the following it more logical.

```
return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+""
```